# ValueError: Requesting 3-fold cross-validation but provided less than 3 examples for at least one class. Any way to get away with this?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, multi-class

I am trying to perform multiclass classification on a 10 class dataset with around 650 data points. But whenever trying to run the code, it gives the above-mentioned error. Although, I understand what does it mean but is there any way to get away with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is this error occurring?

I'm guessing you are using [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)  or [`sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) when the error occurs. Both functions internally use a [`StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) cross-validator, which splits the data into $k$ **stratified** folds. This means that the folds are made in such a way that **the percentage of samples in each class is preserved**. This however requires you to have at least $k$ samples in each class (so that there at least be one sample assigned to each fold), a requirement that your dataset does **not** satisfy.

#### How to fix it?

In order to use it you need to pass an instance of a [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) cross-validator to the `cv` parameter of your functions.

For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score

estimator = ...  # an sklearn estimator
X = ...  # training data
y = ...  # training labels

kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kf)
```

This should solve your problem.

#### Final Notes

If you have a class with less than 3 samples, your models will have a **really** hard time learning this class! If possible, you should consider **obtaining** more data (especially from this class), **merging** some classes together (so that they have more samples), **over-sampling** the minority classes or using a a model that supports **class weighting**.

Comment: I am using CalibratedClassifierCV and I have also raised an issue in GitHub. Here is the link which also has the code  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12030
Also, 'using a model that supports class weighting', can you explain it? Which models support class weighting?

Comment: It is actually not a bug. If you take a look at the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f158e2dfe2af1b23ae3f9d86c598013b2c155c3f/sklearn/calibration.py#L143) it is clearly intentional. In order to make proper stratified folds you **need** at least 1 sample per fold.

Comment: Yes. I get it. But is there any way, I can edit the same code and make it work?

Comment: Yes, [CalibratedClassifierCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html) does have a `cv` parameter you can use to pass a `KFold` cross-validator. Just do it like I showed above. P.S there was a typo in the code I posted; it's fixed now.

Comment: So, after making the changes that you wrote, I won't have to worry about the examples being at least 3 for each class ?

Comment: It will let you bypass the `ValueError` being raised. However, you **should** worry about your classes having few samples, as your models will have a hard time predicting them.

Comment: Okay. I will rather try to merge some of the classes. That way might be helpful as there would be more data points per class.